# html5/css3 DIV on DIVs layout issue

Tags: html

i have div area which is devided in to 4 equal parts, like the one atached.

now i need another div to be placed at the bottom area as an overlay to the above div. Imagine it like a text scroll area on the bottom side of the TV and the TV screen is constructed by 4 divs.

I am able to create the 5 divs. now the issue is that the 5th div(scroll area) is not going above the bottom edge of the 2 lower divs (3 and 4). I also had put z-index also but failed

can anybody share a sample for styling this.
[image: sample-requirement]

Comment: can you provide some code what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it this way:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>
<div class="area"></div>

<div class="overlay"></div>​
```

*CSS:*

```
.area{
  float: left;
  width: 49%;    
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin: -100px;
    left: 50%;
}
​
```

Please note that I have used hard coded example values. The actual values depends on which context the markup is in.

Comment: yeah the position:absolute was missing for me.. it is fixed. and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without your code it's hard to figure what's not working.
If I understand what you want this is what I would have done:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
    <div class="block4"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px; /* use the size you want */
    height: 400px;
}

.container div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.container .block1 { top: 0; left: 0; background: pink; }
.container .block2 { top: 50%; left: 0; background: red; }
.container .block3 { top: 0; left: 50%; background: green; }
.container .block4 { top: 50%; left: 50%; background: blue; }

.container .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px; 
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 30px; /* distance from the bottom */
    z-index: 1;
    background: yellow;
}
```